# Google Cloud HSM as a provider for encryption

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, hsm, jca

AWS seems to allow us to have the AWS Cloud HSM as a provider, See [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cloudhsm-jce-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/cloudhsm/examples/AESGCMEncryptDecryptRunner.java) and [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudhsm-user-guide/blob/master/doc_source/use-cavium-provider.md)

```
Security.addProvider(new com.cavium.provider.CaviumProvider())
```

In the samples from GKE however we seem to only have bouncy castle as a provider. See [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/kms/src/main/java/com/example/Asymmetric.java)

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Maybe i am missing something fundamental.

Would like to do a initsign as below JCA API

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#initSign(java.security.PrivateKey)

Comment: Looking at the sample code - it uses BC for verification and a proprietary client for getting the keys and signing.  Doesn't seem to use JCA but uses a web API - KMS.   You could wrap it up in your own JCA extension :)  https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-java

Comment: Dan, Thanks for looking into it. Cool, so will use AWS or wrap in my own JCA as suggested. I guess i should be grateful for having HSM's in the cloud, would save so much lead time for performing early application behaviour tests. Was wondering if anyone who works for Google could comment. JCA being a standard, would it on the Google Cloud's current or future Roadmap somewhere ? Again Dan, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a JCA provider for Google Cloud HSM (as well as Azure Key Vault and AWS KMS) as part of the [Jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/) project. It performs direct API calls and doesn't rely on the gcloud CLI or the Google Cloud SDK. Usage looks like this:

```
String keyring = "projects/first-rain-123/locations/global/keyRings/mykeyring";
SigningService service = new GoogleCloudSigningService(keyring, token, null);
Provider provider = new SigningServiceJcaProvider(service);

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("GOOGLECLOUD", provider);
keystore.load(null, "".toCharArray());

PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, null);

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA", provider);
sig.initSign(key);
sig.update(data);
byte[] signature = sig.sign();
```

Comment: This is cool. I just wanted to ask of the HSMs in GCP were JCA complaint. Well done! We also did end up doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the exact question is but it looks like you want to write code that signs data using a private key from an HSM and have that work on AWS and Google Cloud. The steps to do that are:

1. Load the provider
2. Open the keystore
3. Retrieve the private key
4. Initialize a signing object with the private key (and update it with the data to sign)
5. Sign

Step 1 can be done programmatically (via *Security.addProvider*, as you have written in your question) or statically in the java.security file. If you want your code to be agnostic to the cloud platform it is running on, you may want to consider doing this statically (although it is also possible to do it programmatically and keep things platform agnostic).

The rest of the steps just require pretty standard JCE code. Below is an example:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("type", "provider name");
PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("alias", null);
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("transformation", "provider name");
sig.initSign(privKey);
sig.update(dataToSign);
byte[] signature = sig.sign();
```

You may want to read the provider name and keystore type from a (secured) configuration file, so those aren't hard-coded. After you get that working you'll want to look at how often you go to the keystore to retrieve key objects and possibly consider caching them because keystore retrievals *can* be expensive, depending on the HSM and provider library being used. That is going a bit beyond the scope of this question, or at least what I am interpreting the question to be, so I will stop there. Hope that helps.